# Why tracking number get from resource API is different from the tracking number recorded in database?

Tags: postgresql, solr, pylons, ckan, paster

I used `resource_show` in [CKAN 2.7.3 API docs](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.3/api/index.html?highlight=api) to get metadata from specific resources. In my `tracking_summary` table, I have some resource which has tracking number larger than 0. However, when I use `resource_show` with `{'include_tracking': True}`, it shows both `recent` and `total` are 0.

My resource record in `tracking_summary` table looks like:

```
                                                       url                                                       | running_total | recent_views 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+--------------
/dataset/d5cd38f4-03df-450e-9eb8-4967bc9741da/resource/844625fb-80a9-445c-85e7-5be8f10ec57b/download/test.csv    |             1 |            1
```

I verified that I have already ran the command of `paster tracking update` and `paster search-index rebuild`. I don't know what am I missing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the cause. If we look at the the `url` we stored in `tracking_summary` table, it does not contain the http schema and domain: `http://example.ckan.com`. However if we are querying a resource from `resource` table, the `url` will contain the full http url. Also, when you tried to call `resource_show` API with `{'include_tracking': True}` in your application, the `get_for_resource(cls, url)` in `Tracking` model will refer to the full `url` instead of the partial one. So if we store the partial one, the `get_for_resource` will fail at the line `data = obj.filter_by(url=url).order_by(text('tracking_date desc')).first()`. Therefore, when we save resource url in `tracking_summary`, we should store the full one such as: `http://example.ckan.com/dataset/<package_id>/resource/<resource_id>/<file_name>`.